# Makefile not updating when dependency changed

Tags: makefile

```
all: ./data/for_analysis.csv ./data/tables/*.docx

./data/for_analysis.csv : ./src/convert-xls-to-gold-standard.py ./data/ED-TRAUMA-DELTA-STUDY_3_2019_total.xlsx 
    python3 $< --rawDataPath $(word 2,$^) --fieldCodesPath ./data/excel_field_codes.json --processedDataPath ./data/for_analysis.csv --logDir ./logs

./data/tables/%.docx : ./src/make-%.py ./data/for_analysis.csv 
    python3 $< --fieldCodesPath ./data/excel_field_codes.json --processedDataPath ./data/for_analysis.csv --logDir ./logs --tablesDir ./data/tables
```

When I update `./src/make-table-2.py`, the second target isn't updated. This behavior doesn't depend on whether `./data/table/table-2.docx` exists or not.

When I run `make` or `make all` even after updating the `py` file, I get the message `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from your question what the state of your targets is *before* you run `make`.  But:

```
all: ./data/for_analysis.csv ./data/tables/*.docx
```

this can't really work, in general.  This tells make, "go find all the files that exist with the filename matching the wildcard `./data/tables/*.docx`".  E.g., that's the same thing you'd get if you run `ls ./data/tables/*.docx` before you started make.

But of course, if you haven't built anything yet then there **are no files matching that pattern**, because that's what you're asking make to build.  So this expands to nothing and make won't do anything with them.

You have to list the targets that you want to build explicitly, or else convert them from the source files you want them to be built from, so you can tell make what it should be building.

For example, maybe:

```
all: ./data/for_analysis.csv $(patsubst ./src/make-%.py,./data/tables/%.docx,$(wildcard ./src/make-*.py))
```

Comment: The bold text was the error. The shell can't enumerate what isn't there. I wound up explicitly enumerating the DOCX files. I couldn't get the suggested pattern substitution to work.

Comment: Enumeration is fine but the pattern will work too, except that I got it backwards.  It should be the source first and destination second.  I will fix the answer.

Comment: Thanks once again. The updated expansion worked and taught me something additional.